# Problems with circular singly linked list iterator

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list, circular-list

I am trying to make an iterator for my circular singly linked list, but I don't undertand how to implement the next() and hasNext() methods. I suspect that I need to either 1) have additional fields in the linked list class or the iterator class, or 2) have references to something else instead of 'head' and 'tail'?
My code is below:

```
public class CircularSinglyLinkedList2<E> implements Iterable<E> {

private Node head;
private Node tail;

public CircularSinglyLinkedList2() {
    head = null;
    tail = null;
}

class Node {
    E data;
    Node next;

    private Node(E data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

private boolean isEmpty() {
    return head == null;
}

private int size() {
    int count = 0;
    if(isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    Node p = head;
    count++;
    p = p.next;
    while(p != head) {
        count++;
        p = p.next;
    }
    return count;
}

public void insert(E data) {
    Node node = new Node(data);
    if(isEmpty()) {
        node.next = node;
        head = node;
        tail = node;
    } else {
        node.next = head;
        head = node;
        tail.next = head;
    }
}

public void delete(E data) {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    if(head == tail) {
        if(head.data == data) {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
        }
        return;
    }
    Node p = head.next, q = head;
    while(p != head) {
        if(p.data == data) {
            q.next = p.next;
            return;
        }
        q = p;
        p = p.next;
    }
}

public Node search(E data) {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    Node p = head;
    if(p.data == data) {
        return p;
    }
    p = p.next;
    while(p != head) {
        if(p.data == data) {
            return p;
        }
        p = p.next;
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean contains(E data) {
    return search(data) != null;
}

public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new SLLIterator();
}


private class SLLIterator implements Iterator<E> {

    private Node p;
    private Node q;

    public SLLIterator() {
        if(!isEmpty()) {
            p = head.next;
            q = head;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() { doesnt't work
        if(p == q || p == head) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() { //doesn't work
        E data = q.data;
        q = p;
        p = p.next;
        return data;
    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to have reasonable `hasNext()` and `next()` methods. What do you mean by _doesn't work_?

Comment: I inserted some random ints, and used a for-each loop to print out the list, but it didn't get all the values. In particular, I think it will always miss the last value in the list, the way it's written.

Answer (score 2):

Your `hasNext()` is not completely correct. Because of your `p == head` condition, you will always miss out printing the last element. So checking `p` will not help in deciding `hasNext()`.

Ideally what you want to check is `q == head`, this is when you finish iterating the all the elements and came back to the starting element and your `hasNext()` should return `false`, but if you simply check `q == head`, it's not going to work because for your starting element itself it will fail. So use a flag to find out whether you came back or you are visiting for the first time.

I would suggest you to do something like this:

use `visitingAgain` flag.

```
boolean visitingAgain = false;
```

Use it in your `hasNext()` like the following.

```
@Override
public boolean hasNext() { 
   if (p == q || (q == head && visitingAgain)){
      return false;
   }
   visitingAgain = true; // once you start iterating change this flag.
   return true;
}
```

**NOTE** I did not check your `insert` and `delete` logic completely, if this does not work just make sure that your other functions are correct. Let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that is exactly what i'm wondering if it's possible to avoid. Do you know if there is any way other than using a boolean or int in hasNext() ?

Comment: There are ways other than using  a boolean or int. But that may not make the code any better than this solution or it could make the code look even worse. IMO, this is a fairly straightforward and clean one.

Comment: @AliMustafa whatever you do, somehow you will have to identify the end, for that you will have to write **some logic**. So I thought simplest thing is to use a flag. Even you want to try something else might, as Codebencher said I think it is not going to make your code any simpler/better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a problem in your iterator. It ignores the last item (the head). For example, imagine that you have just one element in your list. So both `head` and `tail` point to it, as well as `head.next`.

Now, if we ask `hasNext()` on a fresh iterator on such a list, we are supposed to get `true` one time, and then, after we call `next()`, to get false.

But your condition is:

```
   if(p == q || p == head) {
        return false;
    }
```

Which means that for a single-element list, you're going to return `false`, no matter what.

Also, even when we assume we have more than one element, say:

```
2->1
```

Then You initialize the iterator with `p = head.next` and `q = head`. Your `hasNext()` will return true, but what does your `next()` do?

```
public E next() { //doesn't work
    E data = q.data;
    q = p;
    p = p.next;
    return data;
}
```

So, it returns the `2` at the beginning, and moves the `p` and `q`. That's OK, `2` is printed. But now `q` points at the `1` and `p` points again at the `2`. And again, your `hasNext()` sees that `p == head` and says there are no more elements!

So the element currently pointed to by `q`, the actual next element, is ignored.

What you should do is have some sort of a flag that tells you when you hit the head *the second time* as opposed to the first. And there is really no need for two pointers. Here is my version of the iterator:

```
private class SLLIterator implements Iterator<E> {

    private Node p;
    private boolean atStart;

    public SLLIterator() {
        if(!isEmpty()) {
            p = head;
            atStart = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() { 
        if(isEmpty() || p == head && ! atStart) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        E data = p.data;
        atStart = false;
        p = p.next;
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

This iterator has an `atStart` flag which starts out as `true`. So when `hasNext()` is called on a single-item list, it sees that `p` points at the head, but it also sees that this is the first time it does, and so it returns `true`.

And the `next()` method, in this case, will give you the data pointed at by `p`, which is the data in the head. At this point, `atStart` is changed to false, so although `p` is advanced and circles back, and is again `head`, the next time we call `hasNext()`, we won't return `true` again.

And if you have a longer list like `2->1`, you'll get the `2` the first time, and `p` is advanced to the `1` and `atStart` is false.

Now the second time, `hasNext()` sees that `p` is pointing at the `1` which is not the `head` so it returns `true`. And in the `next()` we return the `1`, and advance `p` to the head.

Calling `hasNext()` again will stop because `p` is back to the head, but `atStart` is false.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you know if there is any way other than using a boolean flag or keeping track of the number of nodes?

Comment: No, I don't think there is, as there is no way, in a single-item list designed like this, to know whether the `hasNext()` method has already been called or not. So if it returns `true` once, it will always return `true`, unless you have *something* that keeps track of the number of times it was called. You could "cheat" by using a `q` that's initially `null` and then isn't, but it's the same as having a boolean flag.